# On Microsoft teams when I click allow permission to download file. I got something went wrong message

Tags: json, botframework, microsoft-teams

### Describe the bug

On Microsoft teams application. After I followed and ran [56.teams-file-upload](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/22fcff680a3e11006eb09b81ac5ed4de345933e2/archive/samples/python/56.teams-file-upload), I have click allowed  and it shows the something went wrong message

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Execute 56.teams-file-upload example
2. type something on the bot
3. Press allow in the upload permission
4. See error

Upon clicking it, it should not show the something went wrong

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue, we will check this internally and get back to you.

Comment: This same issue is being tracked at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/issues/632. Kindly follow the github thread for further updates. Thank you.